# Prove by induction that $9^{n+1}+2^{6n+1}$ is divisible by 11

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, induction

I need to prove that $9^{n+1}+2^{6n+1} $ is divisible by $11$ $\forall n\in N$ 
Steps I did:

1. basis step
   $$\\ P(0)\ 11\mid(9+2 ) \ (True)$$
2. inductive step
   $$\\ P(n)\implies P(n+1) \ where: \\  P(n): 9^{n+1}+2^{6n+1} = 11k\\P(n+1): 9^{n+2}+2^{6n+7} = 11k$$
   so $$9^{n+2}+2^{6n+7}=11k\\9^n\times9^2+2^{6n}\times2^7=11k$$
   Then I don't know how to proceed

Comment: Try using $9^{n+1} = 11k-2^{6n+1}$.

Comment: Note: $$9^{(n+1)+1}+2^{6(n+1)+1} = 9\cdot(9^{n+1}+2^{6n+1})+5\cdot11\cdot2^{6n+1}$$

Comment: for $P(0)$, you should have written $11\mid(9+2)$

Comment: modulo $11$, $9^{n+1}+2^{6n+1}=(9^n)(9)+(64^n)(2)\equiv(9)^n(9)+(9)^n(2)\equiv0$

Comment: Don't use $k$ twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hypothesis gives that if $9^{n+1} \equiv r \pmod{11}$ then $2^{6n+1} \equiv -r \pmod {11}$

The induction step follows:
$$\begin{align}P(n+1) &=9^{n+2}+2^{6n+7} \\
&= 9\cdot 9^{n+1}+2^6\cdot2^{6n+1} \\
&\equiv 9 r + 2^6(-r) \\
&= - 55r \\
&\equiv 0 \pmod{11}\end{align}$$

Comment: I just realized how your solution works, and it's easier than I thought, it helped me to solve other exercises of this type as well, what I don't understand is: if I had more than 2 coefficients, how do I understand when who is congruent to r and who to -r?

Comment: @LorisSimonetti when there are more than two terms then we only know that $r_1+r_2+...+r_n \equiv 0$.

Comment: and so now we know that $2^{6n+1} \equiv -r \pmod {11}$ because $9^{n+2}+2^{6n+7}$ is equivalent to $r_1+r_2=0$ so $r_1=-r_2$?

Comment: @LorisSimonetti Yes, you are right.

Comment: Ok, thanks! :-)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

$$9^{n+2}+2^{6n+7}=9\times9^{n+1}+2^6\times2^{6n+1}=9\times(9^{n+1}+2^{6n+1})+55\times2^{6n+1}$$

Comment: I did not understand how 55 came out, but thanks to your comment I still understood how to solve it, thank you!

Comment: $2^6-9=55=5\times11$